# Box API Saver popup

Tags: dropbox-api, box-api, boxapiv2

Is there anything available in the Box API equivalent to this Dropbox Saver?

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/saver

I want users to be able to pick a specific folder to upload to.

If not is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Box File Picker](https://developers.box.com/the-box-file-picker/). This will handle authentication and folder selection. It doesn't do the 'upload file to folder' part of the Dropbox Saver. If that's your ultimate goal you may need to add a [bit of additional code](https://developers.box.com/docs/#files-upload-a-file).

Comment: Ah yes, I've changed the picker to return a shared link and can now select folders. Thanks